# Missing Reference even I Already add

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I Create a Class which will access by my Windows app and excel add ins. In my windows app, I don't have issue in reference the created class but in excel Add Ins I'm getting error.[image]

I already try to select the **EMSDLL.DLL** in *EMSDLL* Project but when i rebuild the excel add ins it will return to the error in the image.

Can you enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you add the reference as a project reference, or a reference to the compiled DLL file?

Comment: Check to make sure that the project **EMSDLL** isn't being compiled to different versions of .NET as **Expense_Monitoring_Addins**

Comment: @John I Try both but still get that error.

Comment: @MickyD EMSDLL is .NET Framework 4.5 and my Add in is .NET Framework 4. I tried to change the framework of the add in but it says that the selected framework is not supported by this project type.

Comment: Ah thought as much.  I would say the VSTO SDK is dictating which version of .NET you can use with the version of Excel you are targeting.  Try to change EMSDLL to be v4 as well

Comment: You can try to check the **Signing** tab in you plugin properties page. Try to use your system certificate instead of a test one